# Default admin menus in Orchard Core?

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

I can create custom menus using my Admin menu class (implements INavigationProvider), but I cannot find where the default menus are being constructed. How is the default admin menu constructed so I can disable, or not create it from C# side?

[image]

Comment: The default menus, like all menus, get created by modules. Its just that some of those modules are included in the CMS. If you enable those modules, they add their menus. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks. that is the answer. I was looking for that "menu generator" in one place but you gave me the idea that every module add their own menus (and its in AdminMenu class, same thing I add my own menus).

Comment: OK then, glad that helped. I'm adding it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default menus, like all menus, get created by modules. Its just that some of those modules are included in the CMS. If you enable those modules, they add their menus.